# How to make a browser trust a self-signed certificate with a user-friendly prompt?

Tags: browser, certificate, trust

Here's the scenario:

1. Website A is served from a public domain `example.com` via HTTPS.
2. Website A needs to access a service B via WebSocket. Thus, the websocket also needs to be secure aka `wss://`.
3. The service B is currently not secured. I'm trying to secure it and I need to generate a certificate for it.
4. The service B is only available from the intranet. The WSS URL starts with `wss://192.168.x.x` (connecting by IP and behind a NAT). Yes, this also means that A can be fully used only from the intranet, although limited functionality is available through the internet. The typical case however is intranet use.
5. The computers which connect to website A aren't in a windows domain and do not currently trust any certificate authority that can be controlled by us. In other words, we cannot create a certificate that all these computers will trust by default. For that we would need to work with one of the large common authorities that everyone trusts, but I doubt they would issue a certificate for a NAT IP address.

The problem:

Since I cannot create a certificate that all the computers trust by default, I might as well create a self-signed certificate and use that to secure the websocket. However... I'm not really sure what will happen. I think that either the user will be prompted each time they connect, or the connection will fail silently anyway.

I can manually install the certificate on each machine, but that requires visiting them each separately, and if a new person wants to access the website, I need to remember to do it on their machine too. Not nice.

Is there some good solution to this? Can you make a website prompt for permanently trusting the certificate or something?

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers have a built in function for permanently trusting unknown certificates, and, to be frank, I wouldn't trust any website, that tried to circumvent those mechanisms, even if they were intranet sites. If something like that appeared while visiting an intranet site, I would be more inclined to call IT Support and ask, if the website has been tampered with.

I would distribute instructions on how to add the certificate (maybe noting that mindlessly doing this on other websites than yours might be problematic) and deal with the cases that are unable to follow these instructions.

An alternative (although I don't have any personal experience with that) might be getting a free certificate from https://letsencrypt.org/ which, as far as I know, will be accepted in most browsers.

Firefox:

[image: https://support.cdn.mozilla.net/media/uploads/images/2015-10-19-09-47-54-63d2a6.png]

Chrome:

https://www.accuweaver.com/2014/09/19/make-chrome-accept-a-self-signed-certificate-on-osx/

Comment: The problem is that the website itself is already running with a trusted certificate, but this one websocket will use an untrusted certificate. Will the browser issue any prompts at all? I'll try to test this in the next few days, but I suspect that it will just silently fail (well, "silently" with a Javascript exception, but for the user that's still silent).

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I'm running towards the same problem only solution I can think about and what I'm trying is that I ask the user to click a button (which creates a pop-up window) with the webserver with the certificate which needs to be accepted. Then they accept the certificate and I ask them to reload (or restart the code by clicking the same button) then it should be able to work. But you will need a page on the w